# How to wait on Async tasks

Tags: c#, task

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action myAction = async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
        Console.WriteLine(Interlocked.Add(ref ExecutionCounter, 1));                
    };

    var actions = new[] { myAction, myAction, myAction };

    Task.WaitAll(actions.Select(a => Execute(a)).ToArray());  //This blocks, right?

    Console.WriteLine("Done waiting on tasks.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int ExecutionCounter = 0;

private static Task Execute(Action a)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
        a();
    });
}
```

This seems simple enough, but naturally the output always looks like this (the order of the numbers change, of course):

> Done waiting on tasks.
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> 3

What am I missing here? Why doesn't `Task.WaitAll` block like I'm expecting it to?

Comment: I don't have an answer, just a thought. Instead of calling execute in the wait all what if you started the tasks on 1 line, then after that called wait all? It's how the example here does it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @chris-crush-code That wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So there are several separate bugs here.

First, for `Execute`, you're using `StartNew` with an `async` lambda.  Since `StartNew` doesn't have a `Task<Task>` returning overload, like `Task.Run` does, you've got a method that returns a `Task` indicating when the asynchronous operation has finished *starting*, not when the asynchronous operation has finished, which means that the `Task` returned by `Execute` will be completed basically right away, rather than after `Delay` finishes or the action you call finishes.  Additionally, there's simply no reason to use `StartNew` or `Run` at all when running asynchronous methods, you can just execute them normally and `await` them without pushing them to a thread pool thread.

Next, `Execute` accepts an `Action`, which implies that it's a synchronous method that doesn't compute any value.  What you're providing is an *asynchronous* method, but as the delegate doesn't return a `Task`, `Execute` can't `await` it.  If you want `Execute` to handle asynchronous methods, it needs to accept a delegate that returns a `Task`.

So given all of that `Execute` should look like this.

```
private static async Task Execute(Func<Task> action)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5));
    await action();
}
```

Next onto the `Main` method.  As mentioned before `Execute` is accepting an `Action` when you're trying to provide an `async` method.  This means that when the action is run the code will continued executing before your actions have finished.  You need to adjust it to using a `Task` returning method.

After all of *that*, your code still has a race condition in it, at a conceptual level, that will prevent you from theoretically getting the results in the right order.  You're performing 3 different operations in parallel, and as a result of that, they can finish in any order.  While you are atomically incrementing the counter, it's possible for one thread to increment the counter, then another to run, increment the counter, print its value, then have the other thread run again and print out the value, given you a possible output of what you have, even after fixing all of the bugs mentioned above.  To ensure that the values are printed in order, you need to ensure that the increment and the console write *are performed atomically*.

Now you can write out your `Main` method like so:

```
int ExecutionCounter = 0;
object key = new object();
Func<Task> myAction = async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5));
    lock (key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(++ExecutionCounter);
    }
};

var actions = new[] { myAction, myAction, myAction };

Task.WaitAll(actions.Select(a => Execute(a)).ToArray());  //This blocks, right?
```

And yes, as your comment mentions, calling `WaitAll` will block, rather than being asynchronous.

Comment: That's excellent. Thanks. 

I was aware of the race condition but that wasn't a puzzle for me. The rest was. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The lambda passed to `StartNew` isn't `async void` (`Action`); it's `async Task` (`Func<Task>`). But it does have similar "early completion" problems since `StartNew` treats `Func<Task>` just like any other `Func<T>` and returns `Task<Task>`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Right, fixed.  Mixed myself up too much with the bug following it and didn't take my time.